# Raycasts stop detecting colliders (or colliders stop detecting raycasts)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I've been working on a basic team-based AI shooting system where the androids can shoot at the humans and the humans at the androids. The system works, and both teams can shoot at and kill each other however once one is killed, it's raycast doesn't seem to detect the enemy's colliders. The result of this is that the bot that killed the other first cannot be damaged by that bot anymore and can therefore "camp" it when it respawns.

**EDIT:** When they respawn they still raycast as normal, it just doesn't detect collisions with the collider(s)

My shooting is done purely by raycasts and to kill / respawn my bots I deactivate them and move them back to their spawn location. The tracking the other team is done via NavMeshAgents and agent.destination. The following are all the scripts that for them. Sorry if it's a lot.

**AndroidShoot Script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AndroidShoot : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject humanTarget;
public GameObject playerTarget;
public PlayerHealth playerHealth;
public allyHealth allyHealth;

public lastShooter lastShot;

float gunDelay = 0.75f;
bool isShooting = false;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    shootGun ();
}

// Name what for the raycast collides with (used to reference the target point)
RaycastHit hit;
void shootGun() {

    Vector3 rayDirection = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().transform.forward;

    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position + transform.up * 1.5f, rayDirection, out hit)) {
        Debug.Log("enemy shoot check");
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + transform.up * 1.5f, hit.point, Color.yellow, 2f);
```

**HumanShoot Script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class humanShoot : MonoBehaviour {

public mainEnemyLife enemyHealth;
public lastShooter lastShot;

float gunDelay = 0.75f;
bool isShooting = false;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    shootGun ();
}

RaycastHit hit;
void shootGun() {

    Vector3 rayDirection = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().transform.forward;

    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position + transform.up * 1.5f, rayDirection, out hit)) {
        Debug.Log("ally shoot check");
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + transform.up * 1.5f, hit.point, Color.black, 2f);

        if(hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag ("Enemy_Torso") && isShooting == false) {
            isShooting = true;
            StartCoroutine (enemyShootAlly ());
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + transform.up * 1.5f, hit.point, Color.cyan, 2f);
            lastShot.shotLastUpdate(this.gameObject.name);
        }
        if(hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag ("Enemy_Head") && isShooting == false) {
            isShooting = true;
            StartCoroutine (enemyShootAlly ());
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + transform.up * 1.5f, hit.point, Color.cyan, 2f);
            lastShot.shotLastUpdate(this.gameObject.name);
        }
        if(hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag ("Enemy_Limb") && isShooting == false) {
            isShooting = true;
            StartCoroutine (enemyShootAlly ());
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + transform.up * 1.5f, hit.point, Color.cyan, 2f);
            lastShot.shotLastUpdate(this.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator enemyShootAlly() {
    Debug.Log("enemy damaged");

    enemyHealth.enemyHealth -= 15f;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (gunDelay);
    Debug.Log ("ally can shoot");
    isShooting = false;
}
}
```

**AndroidHealth Script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class mainEnemyLife : MonoBehaviour {

public float enemyHealth = 100.0f;

public lastShooter lastShooter;
public enemyRespawn enemyRespawn;
public ScoreboardDisplay scoreboardScore;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    enemyDeath();
}

public void enemyTakeDamage(float damage) {
    enemyHealth -= damage;
}

public void enemyDeath() {
    if (enemyHealth <= 0.0f) {
        Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name + " was killed by " + lastShooter.shotLast);
        scoreboardScore.scoreboardIncrease();
        enemyRespawn.respawnEnemy();
        enemyHealth = 100.0f;
    }
}
}
```

**HumanHealth Script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class allyHealth : MonoBehaviour {

public float humanHealth = 100.0f;
public string allyName;

public allyRespawn humanRespawn;
public lastShooter lastShooter;
public ScoreboardDisplay scoreboardScore;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    allyName = this.gameObject.name;
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    humanDeath ();
}
void humanDeath() {
    if (humanHealth <= 0f) {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log(allyName + " was killed by " + lastShooter.shotLast);
        scoreboardScore.scoreboardIncrease();
        humanRespawn.respawnAlly();
        humanHealth = 100.0f;
    }
}
}
```

**AndroidRespawn Script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class enemyRespawn : MonoBehaviour {

public float respawnTime = 1f;
public GameObject enemy;

public void respawnEnemy() {
    StartCoroutine (androidRespawn());
}

IEnumerator androidRespawn() {
    enemy.SetActive (false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (respawnTime);
    enemy.transform.position = this.transform.position;
    enemy.SetActive (true);
    Debug.Log (enemy.name + " has respawned.");
}
}
```

**HumanRespawn Script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class allyRespawn : MonoBehaviour {

public float respawnTime = 1f;
public GameObject ally;

public void respawnAlly() {
    StartCoroutine (humanRespawn());
}

IEnumerator humanRespawn() {
    ally.SetActive(false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (respawnTime);
    ally.transform.position = this.transform.position;
    Debug.Log (ally.name + " has respawned.");
    ally.SetActive (true);
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The more code there is to go through, the less likely people can find your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Well I'm unsure what code is needed to actually help solve it, since I don't know why it's not working properly after the first death. I'm including what might be relevant for it.

Comment: When you disable a GameObject (or component), you stop all coroutines attached to it. Because your shooting routine is terminated when a player dies, it never resets `isShooting` to the default value. Try setting it back to normal on respawn.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found thanks to rutter:

Disabling a GameObject or Component stops the coroutines attached to it and the respawning bot was stuck on isShooting = true so they couldn't fire. I fixed it by setting isShooting = false; in the respawn function.